# C# split() method

Tags: split, c#-3.0

```
string[] separators = { "(#/#)"};
string[] test = test1.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

I want that the "#" are placeholders for all numbers. For example : (3/40) or (64/642)

Comment: Can you give an iput and an expected output ?

Comment: input: (3/40) output: delete